# May a Blue Card holder in Germany work for an Indian company?

Tags: germany, blue-card, india

My Friend has German Blue Card. Can he work on payroll for an Indian Company while living in Germany? He has to work in Germany but on Indian payroll.

Comment: Is the Indian company located in Germany?

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependent on the circumstances and cannot be generally answered.

What type of **residence permit** and **employment in Germany** do they have?

If they have a German employer (i.e. pay taxes and social benefits in Germany) **plus** an extra contract in India, then (when there is no contract conflicts with the German employer) this *may* be possible.

But residing in Germany and **solely** working for an Indian employer, would probably be in violation of the residence permit conditions and considered [Lohndumping](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niedriglohn#Lohndumping).

---

**Sources**:

- [Niedriglohn - Lohndumping](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niedriglohn#Lohndumping)